# Driver python expression doesn't work as intended (doesn't calculate if else properly)

Tags: python, drivers

I can't understand why it doesn't work. Driver value should be 0 according to my expression. Can't figure out what is wrong with it.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't trust the value in a quaternion to exactly equal a whole number.

There are decimal numbers that a base two floating point number can't represent, for the same reason that you can't represent `1/3` exactly in base ten. While `-1` isn't one of those numbers, it's conceivable and probably to be expected that some minute inaccuracy would have been introduced in producing the number that's used for that driver channel.

Try this:

`0 if abs(-1-var) < 0.001 else 1`

or

`0 if var < -0.999 else`

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting, didn't know those "value" numbers might be rounded!

Comment: `math.isclose` is also available `0 if isclose(var, -1) else 1`

Comment: or since booleans convert to ints in drivers in this case could use `1 - isclose(var, -1)` or  `not isclose(var, -1)`

Comment: It says "slow python expression" and refuses to execute it, so I guess no luck here

Comment: @Anna I assume you're referring to `isclose()`? That just means there's more latency/overhead to running it; it should still evaluate. If it's not working, you probably have to set a wider tolerance [(link to documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) to account for the imprecision. E.G. `not isclose(var, -1, rel_tol=1e-3)`. Also, `1 - (abs(-1-var) < 0.001)`,  or `not (var < -0.999)`, or `var > -0.999` etc should work too.

Comment: @Anna Try to enable Auto Run Python Scripts in the Save & Load preferences

Comment: Nope, still have "slow expression"

Comment: @Anna "Slow expression" is more of a info note than an error message. It should still work, unless it also says "Invalid expression". Also, the `abs()` and `< -0.999` ways shouldn't say "Slow expression".